# How to create Regex for Int and Float value using Swift 4.2?

Tags: swift, regex

My scenario, Here I am trying to validate my `pricing` textfield should support and allow only `Integer` and `double` or `float` values. I mean `numbers` with fullstop.

Below `regex` format workin for integers but if value `float` or `double` its not allowing.

My Regex:

```
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$
```

Expected output : 123 and 123.0 // It should allow both.

Comment: [You are using `,` instead of `.`](https://regex101.com/r/eKNIoe/1)

Comment: but ,. both I want to use what I want to do? @ Potato

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/eKNIoe/3)

Comment: Thank you @ Potato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
^[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqdrwI/2)

Comment: Thank you @NeverHopeless